# Is it safe to cast a class to a differnt, binary equal class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, casting

I am wondering if it is safe to case one class to binary-equal class that is nevertheless not the same class.

Background: I want to do some operator-magic without "polluting" the original class (here A).

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int x) { this->x = x; }
    bool operator==(const B& b)
    {
        return x == b.x;
    }
};


    A a;
    a.x = 1;
    B* b = (B*)&a;
    *b == B(1);
```

This works on all my systems, but is it safe/portable to do?

Comment: Who guaranteed binary compatibility to you? The C++ standard surely doesn't.

Comment: No, it's undefined behaviour Read about aliasing.

Comment: Others have said it is undefined.  If you are going to do it anyway, you might want to protect yourself a bit with some static_asserts: #include <cstddef>
static_assert(offsetof(A,x)==offsetof(B,x), "strange compiler behaviour");
static_assert(sizeof(A)==sizeof(B), "strange compiler behaviour");
static_assert(sizeof(A::x)==sizeof(B::x), "strange compiler behaviour");

Comment: @Ian - You know, compilers do lots of things that may seem strange. But they can do them for good reasons. For instance writing specific things into padding bytes, to support various types of diagnostics. It's not that strange, once you *really* think about it. And it's something one should work with, not against. Those static assertions won't protect you, or the OP.

Comment: In this instance you could define a global comparison operators `bool operator==(const A&a, const B&b);` (and/or variants taking `const A&, const A&` or `const B&, const A&`) to do this without the casting.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Talk about an X/Y question! From the faulty premise that comparison with `==` requires a member `operator`, straight to a question about undefined casting hackery.